# : (colon) operator gives error in Phalcon route

Tags: php, phalcon

I have recently upgrade phlacon to Version 4. And below route not woring.

```
http://domain_name/api/30-3-2020-10:00/getdata

$app->post('/api/{date}/getdata', function ($date) use ($app) {
    $get_info = new examplecls();
    $get_info->getData($app, $date);
});
```

This doesn't work.
When I run above api, It gives me method no found error.
When I remove colon (:) operator then its working.
Above route working fine with colon (:) operator in phalcon old version. but in phalcon 4 its not working.

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Anyone help me plese.

Comment: i just spent two hours debugging this and after a while i finally discover that i've overlooked something that made sense. ```Phalcon\Mvc\Router::handle()``` would call [```parse_url()```](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) on the uri and if it has a colon it would return false and thats why it would automatically goes to ```/``` route. check the source code [here](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/Mvc/Router.zep#L624) and [here](https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon/blob/master/phalcon/Mvc/Router.zep#L636)